# iOS SiriKit - INSendPaymentIntentHandling: handle & confirm delegates are not called

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios10, payment, siri

I'm using `INSendPaymentIntentHandling` protocol for Siri Payments.

I followed [Apple Developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH11-SW1) & the sample [code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/IntentHandling/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017335).

The delegate methods `confirmSendPayment`, `resolvePayeeForSendPayment` & `resolveCurrencyAmountForSendPayment` are getting called, where as two delegates `handleSendPayment` & `confirmSendPayment` are not called, below is the Siri Message.

Any help would be appreciated?

**Siri Message:**

> You'll have to continue in `your app`. Would you like to open it?

Note: Deployment Target is iOS 10. Also, I'm using Obj-C language with Xcode 8.3 and iPhone 6S (iOS 10.3).

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: In my case, I was using wrong currency code in resolved INCurrencyAmount object and also using my custom beneficiary object instead of INPerson while resolving payee. After fixing both , it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You must haven’t called `completion(xxx)` in all of your `resolveXXX` method logic.